# What happens when you open wubi.exe in Windows?

Tags: installation, 13.04, wubi

In 7-Zip it showed me the wubi.exe file. I opened it and it just gave me the regular wubi options, I guess (I haven't seen it yet), and I wondered if I selected the intall button if it just installed with windows running. What will happen?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: It doesn't support 13.04 or UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

[Just look here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Wubi installs Ubuntu as any other application of Windows. You can it remove as easily as the applications in Windows…

Comment: okay. I didn't work :p